# Why TCP Client splits data on Android 8.0.1?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that sends data over a WiFi intranet connection and all the data is sent in one package on Android 5 but in several packages in Android 8.0.1

So for the code below in Android 5 I get "This is a test" and in Android 8.0.1

"T" (one packet)

"hi"

" i"

"s"

" a"

" test"

Does anybody would know what is happening?

This is part of the code

```
if(!Connected)
{
    //myClient.addListener();

    myClient = new Socket(serverName, port);
    myClient.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    //myClient.on("new message", onNewMessage);

    Connected=true;
    inFromServer = myClient.getInputStream();
    in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
}

if(Connected)
{
    //updateText.setText("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    OutputStream outToServer = myClient.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

    if(msgToSend.isEmpty())
    {
        out.writeChars("This is a test\r\n");
        //out.writeBytes("This is a test\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        out.writeChars(msgToSend);
        //out.writeBytes(msgToSend);
    }
    out.flush();

    while(waitingData)
    {
        if(in.available()>0)
        {
            XChar = in.readByte();

            if(XChar>=32)
            {
                inBuffer+= Byte.toString(XChar);
            }
            else
            {
                waitingData= false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing packages with your buffers. What does Wireshark show?

Comment: Why did you disable Nagle‘s algorithm?

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm not using Wireshark, I'm connecting my phone to an IoT device and sniffing the UART port(ESP8266) with Hyperterminal and the string is splitted I'm 100% secure.

Comment: @M.Spiller To avoid this situation. But I thought that I was enabling it.

Comment: You set TcpNoDelay to true. I.e. ask to send as fast as possible and not wait for a package to be larger, thus disabling Nagle‘s algorithm and actually provoking this situation. How does it behave when setting to false?

Comment: @M.Spiller Know it seems to work better but seems like I'm getting some not printable characters after my message. I'm going to try to REM the flush() line.

Comment: @M.Spiller I got back to out.writeBytes and now I get the regular 8bits ASCII characters. writeChars() writes in 16bit mode.

Comment: @M.Spiller Now is working ok except for a tinny detail, it send two packets, one for the first byte and one for the rest of the bytes. This is exhausting!

Comment: You cannot avoid that. This is the nature of TCP.

Comment: @M.Spiller My old LG G2 with Android 5 doesn't behave like that; I only get one packet.

Comment: As said, you cannot avoid that. This segmentation is happening inside of the TCP/IP stack. Your other phone most likely has a different implementation. Any application relying on a certain TCP packet size is doomed to fail sooner or later.

Comment: The sender sends a line. The receiver should try to read a line too. Use a buffered reader and use its readLine() member. Then the hassle is over.

Comment: @blackapps As easy as it sound is not. The IoT ESP8266 send to the board microcontroller "+IPD,c,n:p" for every received packet; where c=connection number, n=packet length and p= the actual packet. So I get something like "+IPD,0,2,:Th" then "+IPD,0,2,:is" then "+IPD,0,3,: is" and so on.

Comment: Pretty unclear. If "+IPD,23,12:This is the message" is sent then you will not several times receive  "+IPD...".  That is not a tcp effect. And where is the code that sends that string?

Comment: Further you now said that the esp sends to the board microcontroller and that it receives packets. Packets from who? And where comes sending to Android in play?

Comment: @blackapps My App in android sends to ESP and the ESP is in the same board as the microcontroller, so the ESP send to the microcontroller what it receives from my phone by WiFi.

Comment: @blackapps +IPD,0,2: is created by the ESP to warning the microcontroller that is a new packet, from who, and how many bytes is in length, I just send "This is a test" from the App

Comment: @blackapps What do you mean with "the rest of the info"? The +IPD comment i just to put you more in context since you don't understand why i get +IPD before every packet, as you said, is "pretty unclear".